# Drupal menu tree and Articles

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I use Drupal to manage a news content system with the built-in Article node content type.
I put all my Articles in the main-menu tree because that's the only way I found to display an article and the menu as a side block
on the same page.

for information, my main-menu looks like this :

```
- About
 - Who are we ? 
  -- Another submenu item...
  -- News 
    --- Article1 (disabled)
    --- Article2 (disabled)
```

How can I display a node Article with the menu "About" on the same page without putting articles in the menu tree ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to add a specific article in the About menu link?

Answer (score 0):

[image: selecting where an node can be placed in menu for drupal]

Here you can select the menu where you want it